# Storyboard become red and main.storyboard didnt showing anything after clicked

Tags: xcode, storyboard

My main.storyboard didn't showing anything after I clicked it
and the storyboard became red.

No error or warning about the storyboard.

[image: Picture]

Anyone know about it?